# Facebook access token, session key, sig, and uid

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to Facebook api so my apologies this will be very basic.

How do I find the access token, session key, sig, and uid? Also, when you refer to 'secret' does that mean the api's secret key?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html page, include the following code

```
FB.init({ appId : 'YourAppId', status : true, cookie : true, xfbml : true });
```

Once you add this code. Facebook sets a cookie on you domain. The name of the cookie would be `fbs_YourAppId` .

You can read the cookie and get the access token, session key, sig, and uid.

Alternately you can use a method provided by the Facebook Api Connect.js file to get the feed if the user is logged in.

FB.Api(). Please refer to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.api/ to know more about the method.

do not forget to add facebook connect.js file

secret and the app secret are different.

Comment: Hi Karthik, thank you so much for this. Would this the same for the Open Graph for Flash IDK? Again, I apologies for how basic the question is, I'm such a newbie but very keen to get into this. Thanks again.